# How can I remove tables from my table of contents?

Tags: microsoft-word-2010

Word 2010 is inserting tables - down to some row and column names - into the automatic table of contents of the document.

How can I prevent Word from doing this? I don't want my tables in the ToC - just my document headings.

I know I can convert the ToC to a static list, but I don't want to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The style (on Home tab) of the text you write should not be one of the first three heading styles.

Basically if you want to work with Word's automated features, you have to prepare the document first, make your styles, work with them and then all is simple. Right click on each style, modify and then use them accordingly. What you want to appear in ToC should be marked as heading 1 to 3, and what not, should be heading 4 + or not a heading.

Comment: Thanks - I checked over the tables again and they had heading styles in them. Unusual, because I didn't apply those styles myself...